# python деплой venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Когда переношу проект с PyCharm (сами файлы проекта хранятся локально на пк), на vds или просто пытаюсь запустить файл через дефолтную IDLE, то выскакивает ошибка подключения модулей, которые лежат в других директориях проекта. Я так понимаю, что это из за того что не перенесено виртуальное окружение(сама папка venv в корне проекта перенесена) или какие то настройки путей, которые создала IDLE PyCharm при разработке. Хотелось бы в деталях узнать как решить проблему.

Comment: Может, Вы просто забыли активировать виртуальное окружение?: `source venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, тоесть после переноса файлов на сервер, я там должен выполнить эту команду?

Comment: Да. Если Вы используете виртуальное окружение, Вы везде должны выполнять эту команду перед запуском. Просто PyCharm делает это автоматически.

Comment: Кстати, переносить папку с `venv` — плохая идея. Обычно переносят только зависимости (например через `requirements.txt`), а окружение заново создают.

Comment: @nomnoms12, может source venv/Scripts/activate ? , у меня просто нет в папке env папки bin, но есть папка Scripts, в которой лежат activate, activate.bat и Activate.ps1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя просто копировать папку `venv`, потому что она создаётся по-разному в `Windows` и `Linux`. Для каждой системы Вам необходимо заново создавать окружение, а переносить только файл с зависимостями.

1. Активируйте окружение на `Windows` (`PyCharm` делает это автоматически):

   ```
   venv\Scripts\activate.bat
   ```
2. Создайте файл с зависимостями на `Windows`:

   ```
   pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
3. Перенесите файл на сервер
4. Создайте окружение на сервере:

   ```bsh
   python3 -m venv venv
   ```
5. Активируйте окружение на сервере:

   ```bsh
   source venv/bin/activate
   ```
6. Установите зависимости в новое окружение на сервере:

   ```bsh
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

---

**P.S.:**

Документация: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Активация окружения на разных платформах:

[image: Активация окружения на разных платформах]

Деактивация окружения:

```
deactivate
```